# Stop child text increasing parent height in JetPack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to build a layout in Compose, but struggling to restrict the height of the parent (a Row).

On the left of the layout should be an image with a 1:1 aspect ratio, occupying 1/3 the screen width. This should also determine the height of the parent layout.

On the right are 2 Text() blocks in a column, filling the remaining 2/3 screen width. The 2nd (bottom) text block should always be shown,.

The first text block should use all remaining available space. If there isn't enough text to fill the given space, whitespace should push "text2" to the bottom.

If there is too much text to show in the given space, it should show as much as it can, and use an ellipsis to indicate there's more text.

The challenge I'm facing is that the first text block is growing to show all it's content, and increasing the height of the parent row.

Here is my code so far:

```
 Row(modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)) {
                AsyncImage(
                    model = NetworkConstants.imageUrl(imageURL),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .aspectRatio(1f)
                        .weight(1f),// <- WEIGHT AND ASPECT RATIO OF IMAGE SET THE HEIGHT
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                    contentDescription = "Image"
                )
                Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(2f), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween){

                    Text(text = text1, overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis) // <- HOW CAN I STOP THIS FROM GROWING THE PARENT COLUMN/ROW
                    Text(text2)
                }

            }
```

Comment: Can you add screenshots related to current UI and expected UI